# What are the steps to bundle Meteor into a client-side-only IOS app

Tags: meteor

I have tested Cordova as a way to embed a HTML5/JavaScript application into an IOS application without a remote server.

I would like to embed Meteor instead: for my learning, for the reactivity, and so that later I can add a server-side for storing data.

What are the key steps to do this? I would need to use LocalStorage instead of in-memory storage of minimongo. Are there also steps to embed Meteor? Would I also need Cordova to provide a functional environment for Meteor? Are there steps to tell Meteor there is no server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment its not possible to persist storage with local meteor collections. You can create collections without specifying the collection name e.g

```
var MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection(); //(instead of Meteor.Collection("MyCollection");
```

The issue is as soon as you close the application the data will be cleared. So this makes it very difficult to make your app offline only.

There is also a package being worked on to help allow offline collections while a server is not available: https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data#readme

You can still use meteor with cordova and phonegap though, but you will need a data connection. To bundle your cordova application there is a very helpful script: https://github.com/guaka/meteor-phonegap

Comment: Thanks, for my purposes it looks like it's worth exploring further.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an application using cordova, meteor and packmeteor.
For me it works pretty nicely.

I wrote a block post on how you can get started with it [here](http://gerwinbrunner.com/how-to-deploy-meteor-apps-on-mobile-phones-meteor-cordova-packmeteor/).

For the local persistence of data I used [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/Meteor-GroundDB).